# Request to API within while loop with accumulator

Tags: node.js, while-loop, request

Many people have asked on this site how to loop through a list of URLs and make a GET request to each of them. This doesn't exactly serve my purpose, as the number of times I make a GET request will be dependent on the values I get from the initial API request.

As a general outline of what I currently have:

```
var total = null;
var curr = 0;

while (total == null || cur < total) {
    request.get('https://host.com/skip=' + curr, function(error, response, body) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        total = data['totalItems'];
        curr += data.items.length;
    }
}
```

Due to Node.js and how it uses asynchronous requests, this gives me a forever loop, as `total` and `cur` always stay as null and 0 respectively. I'm not really sure how to rework this to use Promises and callbacks, can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a few ways to do this, but the easiest is probably to just recurse on the function that fetches the results.

It's not tested but should be in the ballpark:

```
function fetch(skip, accumulator, cb) {
  // do some input sanitization

  request.get('https://host.com/skip=' + skip, (err, res, body) => {
    // commonly you'd just callback the error, but this is in case you've fetched a number of results already but then got an error. 
    if(err) return cb(err, accumulator);

    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    accumulator.total: data['totalItems'];
    accumulator.items.concat(data.items);

    if(accumulator.items.length === accumulator.total) return cb(null, accumulator);

    return fetch(accumulator.items.length, accumulator, cb);
  });
}

fetch(0, { items: [] }, console.log);
```

Comment: This looks great! My only concern is whether or not node can handle the accumulator gaining a lot of elements. For example, would this program be able to handle 10k+ total items within accumulator.items?

Comment: I don't know, in concept it should be fine depending on your  server specs, but you'd probably need to test. At some point you wouldn't want to do that in memory anyway in case process restart, network jitter, etc, and should consider accumulating into a database or message queue.

Comment: Okay, thank you! After some testing, the only changes I had to make to your proposed solution was on line 10: `accumulator.items = accumulator.items.concat(data.items);`, as concat returns a new array of the concatenated elements; and on the initial call of fetch: `fetch(0, {'items': []}, console.log);`. Items needed to be defined in order for concat to work. Hope this helps future viewers!

Comment: Cool, nice catch.  Updated the answer to reflect  your finding.